# Why is the rectangle not showing?

Tags: java, jframe

I checked this code for hours, but the rectangle is not showing, can anyone tell me why it is not showing?:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        int resx = 700,resy = 500;
        frame.setSize(resx,resy);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("Game");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        try {
            frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\ivans\\Pictures\\Cookies.png")))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(50,50,450,650);
            }
        }, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Every time I try to activate the background, the rectangle is not shown, and every time I activate the rectangle, the background is not shown. Please help!

Comment: are you sure your try{...} body is executing succesfully? having empty catch{} sections is a very bad practice

Comment: What should I put in the "Except" Serction?

Comment: You should print a stack trace and end the program. You're not going to want it to run if reading in an image throws an exception.

Comment: exactly, at least the line `e.printStackTrace();` and maybe some other printing of your own

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the JFrame's contentPane to a JLabel, a container that uses no layout, and so adding a component to it will not allow that component to be displayed unless you fully specify that component's size and position, i.e., its bounds. This is one reason I avoid using JLabels for contentPanes (also that it will not set its preferred size based on the components it holds) and instead in general prefer to do my drawing in a background JPanel's paintComponent method.

Side recommendations:

- You've too much going on in the main method -- unless this program is not for anything other than demonstration purposes
- You set the JFrame's original contentPane (a JPanel) to FlowLayout, but understand that this is meaningless once you change the contentPane.
- Despite your assuming that the contentPane uses FlowLayout, you're trying to add the drawing JPanel into a BorderLayout position, something that doesn't make sense.
- You have an empty catch block, something that almost never should be done.
- Get your images as resources, not files.
- Avoid using absolute file paths and prefer use of relative paths to resources.
- Don't set sizes of things if you can avoid it.
- Avoid so-called "magic numbers", e.g., `g.fillRect(50,50,450,650);` as this makes your code hard to debug and enhance.

For example, something like:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShowRectangle extends JPanel {
    private static final int RECT_X = 50;
    private static final int RECT_Y = RECT_X;
    private static final int RECT_W = 200;
    private static final int RECT_H = 200;
    private static final String URL_SPEC = "https://duke.kenai.com/guitar/DukeAsKeith-daylightSmall.png";
    private BufferedImage img;

    public ShowRectangle(BufferedImage img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    // have same JPanel draw image and graphic element
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }

        // avoid magic numbers
        // g.fillRect(50,50,450,650);
        g.fillRect(RECT_X, RECT_Y, RECT_W, RECT_H);
    }

    // Size the JPanel to the image size
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet() || img == null) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui(BufferedImage image) {
        ShowRectangle mainPanel = new ShowRectangle(image);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShowRectangle");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            URL imageUrl = new URL(URL_SPEC);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui(img));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

If you avoid using "magic" numbers for instance, it's easy to make the black rectangle draggable, since it is now be drawn by variable values, values that you can change inside of a MouseAdapter (MouseListener and MouseMotionListener combined). For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShowRectangle extends JPanel {
    private static final int RECT_X = 50;
    private static final int RECT_Y = RECT_X;
    private static final int RECT_W = 200;
    private static final int RECT_H = 200;
    private static final String URL_SPEC = "https://duke.kenai.com/guitar/DukeAsKeith-daylightSmall.png";
    private int rectX = RECT_X;
    private int rectY = RECT_Y;
    private BufferedImage img;

    public ShowRectangle(BufferedImage img) {
        this.img = img;
        MouseAdapter myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    // have same JPanel draw image and graphic element
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }

        // avoid magic numbers
        // g.fillRect(50,50,450,650);
        g.fillRect(rectX, rectY, RECT_W, RECT_H);
    }

    // Size the JPanel to the image size
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet() || img == null) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private Point p1;
        private Point rectP = null;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            p1 = e.getPoint();
            if (new Rectangle(rectX, rectY, RECT_W, RECT_H).contains(p1)) {
                rectP = new Point(rectX, rectY);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            moveRect(e.getPoint());
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            moveRect(e.getPoint());
            rectP = null;
        }

        private void moveRect(Point p2) {
            if (rectP == null) {
                return;
            }
            rectX = rectP.x + p2.x - p1.x;
            rectY = rectP.y + p2.y - p1.y;
            repaint();
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui(BufferedImage image) {
        ShowRectangle mainPanel = new ShowRectangle(image);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShowRectangle");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            URL imageUrl = new URL(URL_SPEC);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui(img));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but how do you add the layout to the JLabel?

Comment: @user3150362: in my opinion, you don't. I'd use a background JPanel. Hang on.....

Comment: @user3150362: see examples above of what I mean.\

Comment: @user3150362: hello? Please indicate that you've at least looked at the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

Its there just it was going out of boundary and hence not visible.

replace these two lines and check

```
 g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
 g.fillRect(0,0,250,250);
```

Try this,

```
@Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Rectangle clipBounds = g.getClipBounds();
                                System.out.println(clipBounds.getX() +" "+ clipBounds.getY() + " "+ clipBounds.getHeight() + " " + clipBounds.getWidth());

                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(0,0,450,450);
            }
```

You will get 0.0 0.0 10.0 10.0
 as output meaning the fill reactangle container is starting from 0,0 till 10,10 and hence it was not shown

Change the layout to GridLayout() will solve your problem,

```
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        frame.add(new JPanel(new GridLayout()){
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Rectangle clipBounds = g.getClipBounds();
                System.out.println(clipBounds.getX() +" "+ clipBounds.getY() + " "+ clipBounds.getHeight() + " " + clipBounds.getWidth());
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                     g.fillRect(frame.getWidth()/2,0,frame.getWidth(),frame.getWidth());

            }
        }, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

As per doc,

void java.awt.Graphics.fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)

Fills the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width - 1. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height - 1. The resulting rectangle covers an area width pixels wide by height pixels tall. The rectangle is filled using the graphics context's current color.
Parameters:
x the x coordinate of the rectangle to be filled.
y the y coordinate of the rectangle to be filled.
width the width of the rectangle to be filled.
height the height of the rectangle to be filled.

So that's the issue

Comment: Thank You! Though I problem, why does it appear as a small black square rather than taking up 1/2 of the jframe?

Comment: Here is the problem, the picture does not display now